# Vectorize QR in Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, qr-code

Hi I am trying to vectorise the QR decomposition in numpy as the documentation suggests [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), however I keep getting dimension issues. I am confused as to what I am doing wrong as I believe the following follows the documentation. Does anyone know what is wrong with this:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(100,50,50)

vecQR = np.vectorize(np.linalg.qr)

vecQR(X)
```

Comment: What documentation?  Why aren't you just iterating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc: "By default, pyfunc is assumed to take scalars as input and output.". 
So you need to give it a signature:

```
vecQR = np.vectorize(np.linalg.qr, signature='(m,n)->(m,p),(p,n)')
```

Comment: Oh I see - sorry yes I was confused as it said the `signature` argument was optional! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

How about just map `np.linalg.qr` to the 1st axis of the arr?:

```
In [35]: np.array(list(map(np.linalg.qr,  X)))
Out[35]: 
array([[[[-3.30595447e-01, -2.06613421e-02,  2.50135751e-01, ...,
           2.45828025e-02,  9.29150994e-02, -5.02663489e-02],
         [-1.04193390e-01, -1.95327811e-02,  1.54158438e-02, ...,
           2.62127499e-01, -2.21480958e-02,  1.94813279e-01],
         [ 1.62712767e-01, -1.28304663e-01, -1.50172509e-01, ...,
           1.73740906e-01,  1.31272690e-01, -2.47868876e-01]
```