# Numpy vectorization and signature

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I have the following function:

```py
def fun1(a):
    b=a[0]+a[1]
    return(b)
```

I want to vectorize it using:

```py
fun2 = np.vectorize(fun1,signature='(n,m)->(n,1)')
```

the input

```py
input=np.array([
[1 ,2],
[3, 4],
[5, 6]])
```

I need the output like:

```py
fun2(input)=
np.array([[3],[7],[11]])
```

I know I can do it using `np.sum(input,axis=1)` but I am trying to understand the signature so can you help me with the signature?

Edit: I know the function is so simple and it does not need any vectorization but if I am unable to vectorize a simple function I won't be able to vectorize any complex function

understand the signature

Comment: Did you read the docs? What are you confused about specifically? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html

Comment: The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop. You'd be better off using `np.sum`

Comment: your function does `b=a[0]+a[1]`, but then you `return(a)`.  you are returning the same parameter you passed and ignoring the calculation. Do you mean `return b`?

Comment: `With `signature` it's even slower.  `vectorize` is somewhat useful when applied to a function with several inputs, and you want to take advantage of broadcasting.  With just one argument it's an unnecessary layer.

Comment: My long answer from a few weeks ago , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74589308/trying-to-understand-signature-in-numpy-vectorize#74591997

Comment: In another recent SO I claimed it would be better to 'vectorize' a cover like `lambda a1,a2: fun1((a1,a2))`, which needs no signature.

Comment: What's wrong with the pure python `[fun1(a) for a in input]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [187]: def fun1(a):
     ...:     b=a[0]+a[1]
     ...:     return(b)
     ...: 
     ...: fun2 = np.vectorize(fun1,signature='(n)->()')
     ...: 
     ...: input=np.array([
     ...: [1 ,2],
     ...: [3, 4],
     ...: [5, 6]])

In [188]: fun2(input)
Out[188]: array([ 3,  7, 11])
```

`b` is a scalar, so we can't force the output to be (3,1) shape.  You'll have to settle for the (3,)

With your attempt the full traceback (which YOU should have posted) is:

```
In [191]: fun2 = np.vectorize(fun1,signature='(n,m)->(n,1)')

In [192]: fun2(input)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [192], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 fun2(input)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2163, in vectorize.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2160     vargs = [args[_i] for _i in inds]
   2161     vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
-> 2163 return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2237, in vectorize._vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2235 """Vectorized call to `func` over positional `args`."""
   2236 if self.signature is not None:
-> 2237     res = self._vectorize_call_with_signature(func, args)
   2238 elif not args:
   2239     res = func()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2291, in vectorize._vectorize_call_with_signature(self, func, args)
   2289 if outputs is None:
   2290     for result, core_dims in zip(results, output_core_dims):
-> 2291         _update_dim_sizes(dim_sizes, result, core_dims)
   2293     if otypes is None:
   2294         otypes = [asarray(result).dtype for result in results]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:1892, in _update_dim_sizes(dim_sizes, arg, core_dims)
   1890 num_core_dims = len(core_dims)
   1891 if arg.ndim < num_core_dims:
-> 1892     raise ValueError(
   1893         '%d-dimensional argument does not have enough '
   1894         'dimensions for all core dimensions %r'
   1895         % (arg.ndim, core_dims))
   1897 core_shape = arg.shape[-num_core_dims:]
   1898 for dim, size in zip(core_dims, core_shape):

ValueError: 1-dimensional argument does not have enough dimensions for all core dimensions ('n', '1')
```

It can't force the `b` to 2d.  We can do:

```
In [193]: fun2 = np.vectorize(fun1,signature='(n,m)->(1)')

In [194]: fun2(input)
Out[194]: array([4, 6])
```

If I add a `print(a)` to `fun1` we see it just passes the whole 2 array to `fun1`, so the effect is simply adding the  first 2 rows:

```
In [196]: fun2(input)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
Out[196]: array([4, 6])

In [197]: input[0]+input[1]
Out[197]: array([4, 6])
```

See also

[Trying to understand signature in numpy.vectorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74589308/trying-to-understand-signature-in-numpy-vectorize)

With a corrected `fun1`:

```
In [202]: def fun1(a):
     ...:     print(a)
     ...:     b=a[0]+a[1]
     ...:     return np.array([b])
     ...: 
     ...: fun2 = np.vectorize(fun1,signature='(n)->(m)')

In [203]: fun2(input)
[1 2]
[3 4]
[5 6]
Out[203]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 7],
       [11]])
```

`signature` has to match what the function produces, not what you want the result to be.  And pay close attention to what `vectorize` passes to your function.  Guesses and wishes don't count!

Another way of 'vectorizing' this function:

```
In [205]: np.vectorize(lambda a1,a2: fun1((a1,a2)), otypes=[int])(input[:,0],input[:,1])
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
Out[205]: array([ 3,  7, 11])
```

Now you can even pass (3,1) and (3) arrays and get (3,3):

```
In [206]: np.vectorize(lambda a1,a2: fun1((a1,a2)), otypes=[int])(input[:,0,None],input[:,1])
(1, 2)
(1, 4)
(1, 6)
(3, 2)
(3, 4)
(3, 6)
(5, 2)
(5, 4)
(5, 6)
Out[206]: 
array([[ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 5,  7,  9],
       [ 7,  9, 11]])
```

And without the `vectorize` baggage:

```
In [207]: input[:,0,None]+input[:,1]
Out[207]: 
array([[ 3,  5,  7],
       [ 5,  7,  9],
       [ 7,  9, 11]])
```